# Debian+Gnome Remove Libreoffice

Tags: debian, apt, gnome

Is there no way to remove libreoffice* without removing gnome?

If i type `sudo apt purge libreoffice*`

It automatically also wants to remove `gnome`

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the LibreOffice packages only entails removing [the `gnome` metapackage](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/gnome), not GNOME as a whole. Metapackages are treated specially by `apt`; when they are removed along with one of their dependencies, all their remaining dependencies are flagged so that they stay installed (so `apt autoremove` won’t remove them).

If you remove LibreOffice, you won’t lose any other component of GNOME. If you’re on a stable release of Debian, you won’t miss any future changes to the `gnome` metapackage either, since its dependencies shouldn’t change inside a given release.